# Paragraph skip preserving titlesec, titletoc, table of contents, list of figures and indentation

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs, line-spacing, titletoc

I have hard time dealing with paragraph skip while keeping titlesec/titletoc, table of contents, list of figures and indentation the same (this is a french book). I have the following class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
```

In which I consider everything ok in terms of spacing... except paragraph spacing. I don't want any extra space in titlesec/titletoc, table of contents, list of figures and I want a standard french paragraph indentation.

In top of that, I want the space separating two paragraphs be set to the size of `\normalsize`. Currently, I tried,

```
\newlength{\textsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parskip}{\textsize}
```

Indentation is ok, paragraph spacing is ok... but the spacing of elements in titlesec/titletoc, table of contents, list of figures is completely modified.

Then I tried:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\frenchspacing
```

it protects the table of contents and the list of figures but introduces spaces in titlesec/titletoc and seem to remove indentation.

How to :

- protect the table of contents (no extra spacing needed)
- protect the list of figures (no extra spacing needed)
- protect the local table of contents titlesec/titletoc (no extra spacing needed)
- protect the current indentation
- but... introduces a line skip of `\normalsize` between paragraphs?

Comment: I don't quite get you: if you want french spacing, `\parskip=0pt` (or `0pt plus 1pt` if need be). Or do I miss something?

Comment: frenchspacing was just a test. I need `\setlength{\parskip}{\textsize}` keeping the tocs/list of figures the same...

Comment: Could we have a minimal example illustrating the problem? I don't quite see where you have extra spacing.